If I only use Flashlight, do I need to ask for CAMERA permission?
as the title says, I just used FLASHLIGHT permission and here is my FLashlight code
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.isActive
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class FlashlightHelper(
    var context: Context
) {
    private val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    private var cameraId: String? = null
    private var job: Job? = null

companion object {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private var instance: FlashlightHelper? = null

    fun getInstance(
        context: Context
    ): FlashlightHelper {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = FlashlightHelper(context)
        }
        return instance!!
    }
}

init {
    kotlin.runCatching {
        cameraId = manager.cameraIdList[0] ?: "0"
    }
}

fun toggleSOS(
    enable: Boolean,
    timeOn: Int = 300,
    timeOff: Int = 100,
    numberOfFlashes: Int = -1,
    callback: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    job?.cancel()
    if (enable) {
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            if (numberOfFlashes <= 0) {
                while (isActive) {
                    toggleFlashlight(true)
                    delay(timeOn.toLong())

                    toggleFlashlight(false)
                    delay(timeOff.toLong())
                }
            } else {
                repeat(numberOfFlashes) {
                    toggleFlashlight(true)
                    delay(timeOn.toLong())

                    toggleFlashlight(false)
                    delay(timeOff.toLong())
                }
            }
            callback?.let { it(true) }
        }
    } else {
        job?.cancel()
        toggleFlashlight(false)
    }

}

fun toggleFlashlight(enable: Boolean) {
    kotlin.runCatching {
        cameraId?.let {
            manager.setTorchMode(it, enable)
        }
    }
}

I see there are many apps that only turn Flash on and off but still ask for CAMERA permission. Do I need to ask for permission? Because when I don't ask for permission, I can still turn it on and off. Thanks
I see there are many apps that only turn Flash on and off but still ask for CAMERA permission. Do I need to ask for permission? Because when I don't ask for permission, I can still turn it on and off. Thanks

Android devices don't have flashlights. They have flashes for the camera. So yes. You need camera permissions to use the camera flash.

You can use the permission android.permission.FLASHLIGHT to only use the flashlight and not any of the camera stuff

I suspect most of those apps are old and come from days where they still relied on (or at least still support) deprecated Camera API which indeed required it.
